# Drive API v3 restore previous version of file

Tags: google-drive-api

Dropbox has an [restore api endpoint](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-restore) to restore a file to an earlier version. How does one do the same thing using the Google Drive REST API v3? That is, restore a file in Google Drive to its earlier version.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886437/how-to-revert-back-document-to-a-previous-revision?rq=3

Answer (score 2):

You restore a revision by deleting all later revisions using https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/delete

So eg, You have a file with revisions:-

> 9
>
> 7
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 1

and you want to restore revision 5, you must delete revisions 9 and 7

Comment: You can use it for binary files on Drive, but doesn't work for Google Docs (response of the API on revision delete):

`"message": "The file does not support deleting revisions."`

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive API has its own way of managing history of revisions. This is found in the [Manage Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-revisions) docs.

To have access of a file's available revision history, use the [Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list). Choose a revision number and use that number in [Revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/get) to be able to download it or perform other operations. You can also publish the revision as stated in the guide of [Publish a revision](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-revisions#publish_a_revision):

> To publish a Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides revision, you set the published property for that file in the Revisions property. This property can't be set for Google Sites revisions via the Drive API.

More of that in this [Google video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGraiS9m80U).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does nothing to address the point of the question which is how to restore a revision using the Drive API.

Comment: did you even bother reading the guide? You cant always have it readily on the plate.

Comment: Yes, I read it before posting my question. If the material you referenced does not provide the solution, why did you reference it?

Comment: Question, did you try the [Revisions.list Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list#try-it)?

Comment: How is trying Revisions.list going to restore a revision?

Comment: I saved two named versions thinking I would be able to restore them by clicking somewhere. Where is the where? What is the point of saving if you cannot restore?

Comment: @aNewb Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886437/how-to-revert-back-document-to-a-previous-revision?rq=3