# revert a sheet to a previous version with button or on schedule

Tags: google-apps-script, version-control, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script for a sheet to make it revert to a previously named version on a nightly basis, OR tie the script to a "button" of sorts within the sheet.  I can't seem to find/figure out any method that'll enable this possibility.  Can any pros point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to revert to previous version automatically.

Comment: I haven't tested it but try to consider using the [Advance Google Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) for Drive API in Apps Script. In that Advance Service you can manage the revisions and this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43447756/5995040) will guide you on how to load to your file from the previous version. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Rebot!  It's been nothing but dead ends from within the script editor, and I figured I had to delve outside of that to make something that works for me.  Hopefully this is the direction I'm looking for!